# Preferred locations in Cosmos DB SDK v3

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

In CosmosDB SDK v2 it is possible to setup preferred locations during client creation (via [ConnectionPolicy.PreferredLocations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.connectionpolicy.preferredlocations?view=azure-dotnet) setting). However, I don't see similar setting in Cosmos DB SDK v3. As per my understanding, the closest setting in v3 is [CosmosClientOptions.ApplicationRegion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmosclientoptions.applicationregion?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_CosmosClientOptions_ApplicationRegion), but it allows to provide single region only.

Is there a way to to setup list of preferred locations in SDK v3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

V3 SDK takes a different approach. By specifying the `ApplicationRegion` (the region where your app is actually running), it will automatically populate the priority of regions based on proximity and account availability (the regions your account is provisioned to) to optimize latency.

If your app runs in West US and your Cosmos DB account is in East US, Europe, and West US, when you set the `ApplicationRegion` to West US, it will automatically create the preferred list as West US, East US, and Europe (order of distance).

You just need to focus on defining which region your application runs.

Comment: If the most preferred CosmosDB region is temporarily unavailable, then next region in priority list will be used to serve requests, right?
In v3 SDK, is there a way to programmatically get CosmosDB region, which is used to serve requests? (something similar to DocumentClient's [ReadEndpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.readendpoint)/[WriteEndpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.writeendpoint) properties)

Comment: See [AccountProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.accountproperties?view=azure-dotnet), and [ReadAccountAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmosclient.readaccountasync?view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: CosmosDB sdk v3.8 brings [ApplicationPreferredRegions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmosclientoptions.applicationpreferredregions?view=azure-dotnet) support, which can be used as an alternative to `ApplicationRegion`

Comment: What if I do not specify any region, will the client pick from all the available regions I have?

Comment: @Yiping your question is answered in this document's first section https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/troubleshoot-sdk-availability